# Digital IC that draws power from data pins

Tags: power, digital-logic

Just a hypothetical question, are there any digital IC or digital circuit that does not have to have a dedicated power pin, but instead draws DC from data pins (Phantom Power). If there are, what are typical examples?

I'm inclined to think no, but I think my knowledge in digital electronics is very, very lacking.

Comment: Dallas 1 wire is an example. I've used a temp sensor that can source power from the serial line.

Comment: Many digital ICs can be powered via the protection diodes on the inputs, but such operation is highly unrecommended.

Comment: In RF design, it's not uncommon to send DC power and RF signal through the same coaxial cable.

Comment: Anecdotally, the first ARM chips at Acorn would run without the power line being connected: [Sophie Wilson, Acorn and the development of ARM](http://www.linuxvoice.com/sophie-wilson-acorn-and-the-development-of-arm/).

Comment: So will many modern ARM MCU's and likely other architectures as well.  Pretty much anything with I/O protection diodes will *attempt* to if you break the rules about I/O vs supply voltages, but more power hungry devices will exceed the rating of those diodes in doing so.   If an I/O is driven before power, some devices will also get into a state from which they cannot then power-on-reset when actual supply power is applied.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are commercial chips that make use of this concept.  The best known are the [1-Wire](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1796) IC's from Dallas Semiconductor/Maxim; many are various kinds of sensors.  "1-wire" is a bit of a misnomer, as two wires are of course needed including ground.

A typical chip is the [DS18S20](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18S20-PAR.pdf) digital thermometer:

[image]

Note even though the thermometer is packaged in a three-pin TO-92 package, **only two pins are used**, 1 (GND) and 2 (DQ-Data in/out).  Pin 3 is a NC (no connect).  So there is no V\$_{CC}\$ supply pin.

The make use of a concept called parasite (or parasitic) power.

[image]

Instead of the V\$_{CC}\$ pin, power is harvested off the data line which is normally kept high (either 3.3 or 5V) by a pullup resistor back at the host microcontroller.  This keeps the capacitor, typically 800 pF charged.

Incoming data is directly read off of the data line using either a buffer or inverter as shown in the diagram.  Outgoing data is sent back to the host by enabling the MOSFET across the data and return lines, which temporarily shorts them together (the current will be limited by the pull-up resistor).

When data is sent on the line in either direction, the line is temporarily brought low.  When this happens, the diode keeps the capacitor from being discharged, and the capacitor keeps the chip powered.

Another example of parasite power, this time not in an IC, but an RS-232 level shifter that doesn't need a charge pump:

[image]

[RS-232 signal levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Voltage_levels) are -3 to -15v marking (idle), and +3v to +15v spacing (active).  (PC's typically use -5V and +5V since they fall within that range.)  Level shifters must be used to converter the RS-232 levels to the TTL signal levels used by the UART in a microcontroller, and also to reverse their polarity (for the UART, high is idle, and low is asserted, opposite of RS-232).

Going from the RS-232 TX output from the PC to the input of the UART is simple, use the  positive (asserted) voltage to ground the TTL RX lead via Q2, and ignore the negative voltage so the TTL RX lead will be pulled high by resistor R1 in the diagram.

Going the other way, a low level on TTL TX will result in V\$_{CC}\$ (typically 5V) placed on the PC RX lead.  But where to get a negative voltage without a negative supply?  Since the PC TX lead is normally negative, it is used to charge up the capacitor C1 through the diode, much like the 1-Wire circuit.  This voltage is then used to keep the PC RX lead negative when it is not being asserted.

Comment: That level shifter sounds like a neat idea, until you try and interface two of them with each other...

Comment: A diode from V- to ground will cure that.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I may be wrong, but I thought immibis might be jokingly referring to connecting two microcontrollers back to back with an RS-232 cable and two interfaces, each one trying to get -5 V from the other.  Actually this would work okay, as the receive side of the interfaces don't need the negative voltage to operate.

Comment: But when the transmitter transmits only 0-5V, the level on C1 would rise much more quickly than intended. 'My' diode would keep the level at GND+0,6V.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat related - though not exactly the same thing - are RFID tags where the power to operate the tag comes from the RF energy.  There is even an implementation with an [ATtiny that uses power captured through a GPIO pin's ESD protection diode](https://hackaday.com/2018/01/05/attiny-chip-abused-in-rfid-application/) to provide enough power to the core to emulate a standard RFID tag.